# Send Survey Notification from Standalone Application

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, salesforce-classic

As per Winter 20 release, we can automate "Survey Invitations" from Process Builder.
But there is one use case for me.

Is there any possibility to automate the same "Survey Invitations" from lightning component or standalone application?

I have tried one scenario like :-

I have created one Boolean custom field for object and updating that field from apex class. Then after making condition in process builder(When thesend_Survey_Notification__c = true)  and calling the "Send Survey Notification" action. But not able to get the notifications.

Below is the code:-

public static CaseUpdateResponse updateCases(List cases) {          for (CaseManager__c ct : cases) {
                if(ct.UserAction__c == 'Make Available'){
                   ct.send_Survey_Notification__c = true;
                }
            }
    update cases;
}

Thanks,
Ragav

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=task_send_generate_link.htm&type=5) has information on how to get a survey link:

> 1. In the Survey Builder, select Send | Get Link.
> 2. Select whether you want to send your survey to participants within
>    your company or outside your company.
> 3. Select the settings for your survey invitation.
> 4. Copy the survey link, and send it to your participants.

Once you get the link you can use this behind lightning component or whereever you want